# Hide frame in custom ContentView

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I'm using a content view page called `CardViewTemplate.xaml` in my `ListView` to render some content with two frames, one of them should be visible and the other not, at the same time.

```
        <ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        ...>
        <Frame  IsVisible="{Binding IsNotBreak}" IsClippedToBounds="True">
    .... content ....
        </Frame>
        <Frame IsVisible="{Binding IsBreak}" IsClippedToBounds="True">
    --content 2-
        </Frame>
      </ContentView>
```

and the above page used in list view to bind and view some data to listview like below code:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" SelectedItem="{Binding SelcetedItem,Mode=TwoWay}" 
          RowHeight="-1" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCard}" HasUnevenRows="True"   >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Custom:CardViewTemplate/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Unexpectedly  my list view shows only the second frame and it looks like attached image:

[image: Frame 1 Doesn't view any Content]

Answer (score 0):

That is because `ContentView` is supposed to have only one child, and the second `Frame` is overriding the first `Frame`.

Try adding a view-container like `AbsoluteLayout`, or `Grid` to hold the two frame(s) inside `ContentView`:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    ...>
    <AbsoluteLayout>

        <Frame  IsVisible="{Binding IsNotBreak}" IsClippedToBounds="True">
    .... content ....
        </Frame>
        <Frame IsVisible="{Binding IsBreak}" IsClippedToBounds="True">
    --content 2-
        </Frame>

    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentView>
```